# Remove character in c++ with cstring

Tags: c++

I want to remove the - caracter from my sentence!
there is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[101];
    cin.getline(a,101);
   for(int i=0;i<=strlen(a)-1;i++){
       if(a[i]=='-'){
           a[i]=' ';
       }
   }
   cout<<a;
}
```

And i run this:
`i had -34 ms`
I need this answer:
`i had 34 ms` but i get this: `i had  34 ms` a space in plus!

Comment: You need to shift the characters to the left. Not replace - with a space.

Comment: a[i]=a[i-1] , i'ts okey?

Comment: can't understand .

Comment: `if(a[i]=='-'){ for(int j=i; j <= strlen(a) -1;++j) { a[j]=a[j+1]; } }`